# Search Array Error

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans

I am having an issue using netbeans with this program. The program is used to search via an array from an imported text file and the text file has several columns and rows, pertaining to several characteristics of cars (i.e. License Plate Numbers). You need to create dialog boxes to search what your looking for, for each option. The problem is at the end of the code snippet starting with one.setPlate. All of the one.set(x) is being flagged, what could be the reason?

```
package vehiclesearch;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class VehicleSearch {
    private static String[] sliced;
    public static void main
    (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {String NameOfFile =   
       JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Where is the File Path to Import Located at?");
    File textFile = new File((NameOfFile));
    Scanner in = new Scanner (textFile);

    //Imports the appropriate text file named "vehicles.txt"//
    ArrayList <String> carsArrayList = new ArrayList <>();
    while(in.hasNextLine()){
        String line = in.nextLine();
        carsArrayList.add(line);
    }
    in.close();
    ArrayList<VehicleSearch> vehicleObs = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i= 0; i <carsArrayList.size(); i++){
    String temp = carsArrayList.get(i);
    VehicleSearch VehicleClass = new VehicleSearch ();
    String[] sliced = temp.split("\\s+");

    vehicleClass.setPlate(sliced[0]);
    int a = Integer.parseInt(sliced[1]); 
    vehicleClass.setYear(a);
    vehicleClass.setMfg(sliced[2]);
    vehicleClass.setStyle(sliced[3]);
    vehicleClass.setColor(sliced[4]);
    vehicleObs.add(vehicleClass);

         boolean stepTwo = true;

                while(stepTwo) {
                    String search;
                    search = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose one of the following search options" + "1 Plate" + "\n" +"2 Year" + "3 Manufacturer" + "\n" + "4 Body Style"+ "\n"+ "5 Color");
                    int searchOption = Integer.parseInt(search);
                    String searchVal;
    searchVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a value to search for" + "\n" + "All values must be exact in wording, please be careful when using Caps or check for Caps Lock");
                    searchDialogs(vehicleObs, searchOption, searchVal);

    String c;
    c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type S to search | E to exit");
    String b = "S";
    if(c.equalsIgnoreCase(b)){
    stepTwo = true;
    }
    else{
    stepTwo= false;
    }
    }
    }
    }
    public static String plateCheck(ArrayList list, String search){

        ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
                String temp = list.get(i).toString();
                if(temp.contains(search)){
                    as.add(list.get(i).toString());
            }
        }
        return alFormat(as);
    }
    public static String yearCheck(ArrayList list, String search){
        ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            String temp = list.get(i).toString();
            as.add(list.get(i).toString());
        }
        return alFormat(as);
    }

    public static String mfgCheck(ArrayList list, String search){
        ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            String temp = list.get(i).toString();
            as.add(list.get(i).toString());
            }
        return alFormat(as);
        }

    public static String StyleCheck(ArrayList list, String search){
        ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            String temp = list.get(i).toString();
            as.add(list.get(i).toString());
        }       
            return alFormat(as);
    }

    public static String colorCheck(ArrayList list, String search){
        ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            String temp = list.get(i).toString();
            as.add(list.get(i).toString());
        }
        return alFormat(as);
    }

    public static void searchDialogs(ArrayList vehicleObs, int searchOption, String 
    searchVal){
    if(searchOption == 1){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your following search yielded the following 
    results" + "\n" + plateCheck(vehicleObs, searchVal));
    }//Outputs data (Plate Numbers) from the text file imported
    else if(searchOption == 2){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your following search yielded the following 
     results" + "\n" + yearCheck(vehicleObs, searchVal));
    }//Outputs data (Year) from the text file imported
    else if(searchOption == 3){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your following search yielded the following 
    results" + "\n" + mfgCheck(vehicleObs, searchVal));
    }//Outputs data (Manufacturer) from the text file imported
    else if(searchOption == 4){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your following search yielded the following 
    results" + "\n" + styleCheck(vehicleObs, searchVal));
    }//Outputs data (Style) from the text file imported
    else if(searchOption == 5){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your following search yielded the following 
    results" + "\n" + colorCheck(vehicleObs, searchVal));
    }//Outputs data (Color) from the text file imported
    else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry no results have been found");
    }//will only output this message only if nothing is found,//
    }

    public static String alFormat(ArrayList too){
        String tmpString;
        String full = "";
        for( Object aValue | too){
            tmpString = aValue + "\n";
        full = full + tmpString;
    }
            return null; 
    }
    }

   //Vehicle Class//


 public class VehicleClass {
  protected String plate;//car plate
   protected int year;//car model year
   protected String mfg;//manufacturer
   protected String style;// car style
    protected String color;//color of car

 public VehicleClass(){
 plate = null;
 year = 0000;
 style = null;
 color = null;
 }
  public VehicleClass (String e , int r, String g, String y, String c){

 plate = e;
 year = r;
 mfg = g;
 style = y;
 color = c;
 }
 public VehicleClass copyVehicle(VehicleClass k){
 VehicleClass k1 = new VehicleClass();
 k1.setPlate(k.getPlate ());
 k1.setYear(k.getYear());
 k1.setMfg(k.getMfg());
 k1.setStyle(k.getStyle());
 k1.setColor(k.getColor());
 return k1;
 }
 public void setPlate(String e){
 plate= e;
 }
 public void setYear(int r){
 year = r;
 }
 public void setMfg(String g){
 mfg = g;
  }
  public void setStyle(String y){
  style = y;
  }
  public void setColor(String c){
  color = c;
   }
   public String getPlate(){
   return plate;
    }
    public int getYear(){
    return year;
     }
   public String getMfg(){
    return mfg;
   }
   public String getStyle(){
   return style;
   }
    public String getColor(){
   return color;
     }
@Override //need this?
public String toString(){
 return (plate + "\t" + year + "\t" + mfg +"\t"+ style + "\t" + color);
  }
  }




//Text File to import//
A3245D  2009    Ford      sedan      white
B3396   2011    GMC   pickuup    blue
S214X   2010    Toyota    sedan      white
TR3396  2009    BMW   sedan      black
XR295   2011    Honda     pickuup    red
Z2349A  2012    Toyota    suv        silver
IMAQT   2009    Honda     suv        blue
```

Comment: What do you mean "All of the one.set(x) is being flagged"? Can you explain a bit.

Comment: for example,  one.setPlate, one.setYear, one.setMfg, one.setStyle, one.setColor.

Comment: yes yes it is clear. But what do you mean by flagged?

Comment: NetBeans error: Create method "setPlate(java.lang.String)" in vehicleserach.VehicleSearch.   The same error goes for setYear, setMfg,setStyle, and setColor.

Comment: Can you show the vehicleserach.VehicleSearch code as well?

Comment: The error is in VehicleSearch one = new VehicleSearch ();. one must be a VehicleClass. (Not a VehicleSearch).

Comment: Did I fix it correctly?

Comment: I updated the answer. Can you check with it.

Comment: Several errors still popping up. For the main class [code] VehicleClass one = new VehicleClass (); //NetBeans wants to create constructor// and then for the vehicleClass [code] public  class VehicleClass(){
    plate = null;
    year = 0000;
    style = null;
    color = null;
} //Netbeans says cannot find symbol for each line here//

Comment: Also for the vehicle class: [Code]k1.setPlate(k.getPlate ());
    k1.setYear(k.getYear());
    k1.setMfg(k.getMfg());
    k1.setStyle(k.getStyle());
    k1.setColor(k.getColor());
    return k1; //Netbean error: Create method "setPlate(java.lang.String)" in vehicleclass.Vehicleclass.vehicleclass//

Comment: Found the solution, netbeans was corrupted the reason why your recommendations and from others did not reflect myresults. Thank you for your time and effort. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

I did some corrections in there. Now it is working. I checked with plate. Can you check it. I think code can be improved further.

**VehicleSearch.java**

```
    public class VehicleSearch {

    private static String[] sliced;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String NameOfFile =   JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Where is the File Path to Import Located at?");
        File textFile = new File((NameOfFile));
        Scanner in = new Scanner (textFile);

        //Imports the appropriate text file named "vehicles.txt"//
        ArrayList <String> carsArrayList = new ArrayList <String>();
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            String line = in.nextLine();
            carsArrayList.add(line);
        }
        in.close();
        ArrayList<VehicleClass> vehicleObs = new ArrayList<VehicleClass>();

        for (int i= 0; i <carsArrayList.size(); i++){
            String temp = carsArrayList.get(i);
            VehicleClass one = new VehicleClass ();
            String[] sliced = temp.split("\\s+");

            one.setPlate(sliced[0]);
            int a = Integer.parseInt(sliced[1]); 
            one.setYear(a);
            one.setMfg(sliced[2]);
            one.setStyle(sliced[3]);
            one.setColor(sliced[4]);
            vehicleObs.add(one);

            boolean stepTwo = true;

            while(stepTwo) {
                String search;
                search = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose one of the following search options" + "1 Plate" + "\n" +"2 Year" + "3 Manufacturer" + "\n" + "4 Body Style"+ "\n"+ "5 Color");
                int searchOption = Integer.parseInt(search);
                String searchVal;
                searchVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a value to search for" + "\n" + "All values must be exact in wording, please be careful when using Caps or check for Caps Lock");
                searchDialogs(vehicleObs, searchOption, searchVal);

                String c;
                c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type S to search | E to exit");
                String b = "S";
                if(c.equalsIgnoreCase(b)){
                    stepTwo = true;
                }
                else{
                    stepTwo= false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static String plateCheck(ArrayList list, String search){

        ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            String temp = list.get(i).toString();
            if(temp.contains(search)){
                as.add(list.get(i).toString());
            }
        }

        return alFormat(as);
    }
    public static String yearCheck(ArrayList list, String search){
        ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            String temp = list.get(i).toString();
            as.add(list.get(i).toString());
        }
        return alFormat(as);
    }

    public static String mfgCheck(ArrayList list, String search){
        ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            String temp = list.get(i).toString();
            as.add(list.get(i).toString());
        }
        return alFormat(as);
    }

    public static String styleCheck(ArrayList list, String search){
        ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            String temp = list.get(i).toString();
            as.add(list.get(i).toString());
        }       
        return alFormat(as);
    }

    public static String colorCheck(ArrayList list, String search){
        ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            String temp = list.get(i).toString();
            as.add(list.get(i).toString());
        }
        return alFormat(as);
    }

    public static void searchDialogs(ArrayList vehicleObs, int searchOption, String 
            searchVal){
        if(searchOption == 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your following search yielded the following results" + "\n" + plateCheck(vehicleObs, searchVal));
        }//Outputs data (Plate Numbers) from the text file imported
        else if(searchOption == 2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your following search yielded the following results" + "\n" + yearCheck(vehicleObs, searchVal));
        }//Outputs data (Year) from the text file imported
        else if(searchOption == 3){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your following search yielded the following results" + "\n" + mfgCheck(vehicleObs, searchVal));
        }//Outputs data (Manufacturer) from the text file imported
        else if(searchOption == 4){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your following search yielded the following results" + "\n" + styleCheck(vehicleObs, searchVal));
        }//Outputs data (Style) from the text file imported
        else if(searchOption == 5){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your following search yielded the following results" + "\n" + colorCheck(vehicleObs, searchVal));
        }//Outputs data (Color) from the text file imported
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry no results have been found");
        }//will only output this message only if nothing is found,//
    }

    public static String alFormat(ArrayList too){
        String tmpString;
        String full = "";
        for( Object aValue : too){
            tmpString = aValue + "\n";
            full = full + tmpString;
        }
        return full; 
    }
}
```

**VehicleClass.java**

```
 public class VehicleClass {
    protected String plate;//car plate
    protected int year;//car model year
    protected String mfg;//manufacturer
    protected String style;// car style
    protected String color;//color of car

    public VehicleClass(){
        plate = null;
        year = 0000;
        style = null;
        color = null;
    }
    public VehicleClass (String e , int r, String g, String y, String c){

        plate = e;
        year = r;
        mfg = g;
        style = y;
        color = c;
    }
    public VehicleClass copyVehicle(VehicleClass k){
        VehicleClass k1 = new VehicleClass();
        k1.setPlate(k.getPlate ());
        k1.setYear(k.getYear());
        k1.setMfg(k.getMfg());
        k1.setStyle(k.getStyle());
        k1.setColor(k.getColor());
        return k1;
    }
    public void setPlate(String e){
        plate= e;
    }
    public void setYear(int r){
        year = r;
    }
    public void setMfg(String g){
        mfg = g;
    }
    public void setStyle(String y){
        style = y;
    }
    public void setColor(String c){
        color = c;
    }
    public String getPlate(){
        return plate;
    }
    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }
    public String getMfg(){
        return mfg;
    }
    public String getStyle(){
        return style;
    }
    public String getColor(){
        return color;
    }
    @Override //need this?
    public String toString(){
        return (plate + "\t" + year + "\t" + mfg +"\t"+ style + "\t" + color);
    }
}
```

**vehicle info file**

```
AB-2323 1900 Japan Sport Black
AB-2323 1990 German Business White
AB-2323 2000 USA Army Blue
```

Comment: I've added the vehicle class with the setters and getters, along with the entire main class code.

Comment: Do you want the text file as well?

Comment: I've changed the code a bit from a request from another member, I also added the text file.